# pointcloud_to_laserscan catkin_make fail

Tags: ros, navigation, kinect, ros-hydro, pointcloud-to-laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm am trying to utilize the Microsoft Kinect for navigation.  I am utilizing ROS Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04.

I have not figured out how to use the navigation stack yet, so if you have any pointers on that, send them my way.

I have noticed that most of the navigation packages require `/laserscan` rather than`/pointcloud2`, so I have begun to try to get [pointcloud_to_laserscan](http://wiki.ros.org/pointcloud_to_laserscan) up and running.

I downloaded the package utilizing:

```
git clone https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl.git
```

but when I ran `catkin_make` I received the following error:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package tf2_sensor_msgs.

  Set tf2_sensor_msgs_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration
  file for tf2_sensor_msgs.  The file will have one of the following names:

    tf2_sensor_msgsConfig.cmake
    tf2_sensor_msgs-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  perception_pcl/pointcloud_to_laserscan/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)



CMake Error at perception_pcl/pcl_ros/CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package):
  Could not find module Findcmake_modules.cmake or a configuration file for
  package cmake_modules.

  Adjust CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to find Findcmake_modules.cmake or set
  cmake_modules_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file
  for cmake_modules.  The file will have one of the following names:

    cmake_modulesConfig.cmake
    cmake_modules-config.cmake

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

I'm relatively new at this.  Any thoughts?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204575/pointcloud_to_laserscan-catkin_make-fail/) by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on ROS Answers with karma: 323 on 2015-03-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2018-06-17**:
Hi, Did you convert pointcloud to laserscan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is because you cloned the repo, but did not install any dependencies. To install dependencies you would run:

> rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro hydro -y

Incidentally you cloned the indigo-devel branch by default, which will not work on hydro.

Why not just install the binaries via apt-get? This will pull in all dependencies automatically:

> sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-pointcloud-to-laserscan

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2015-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2015-03-09**:
Good question...

sudo apt-get worked just fine.

Thanks.